# How to recover matplotlib defaults after setting stylesheet

Tags: python, matplotlib

In an ipython notebook, I used a matplotlib stylesheet to change the look of my plots using

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
%matplotlib inline
style.use('ggplot')
```

My version of matplotlib is 1.4.0. How do I go back to the default matplotlib styling? I tried all the available styles in

```
print style.available
```

but there doesn't seem to be a "default" option. I also tried

```
matplotlib.rcdefaults()
```

For some reason, this gives me a gray background. It also changes the text from gray (ggplot style) to black, which may be the default, but also could be another random style.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You should be able to set it back to default by:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)
```

In `ipython`, things are a little different, especially with `inline` backend:

```
In [1]:

%matplotlib inline
In [2]:

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [3]:

inline_rc = dict(mpl.rcParams)
In [4]:

plt.plot(range(10))
Out[4]:
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x72d2510>]
```

[image]

```
In [5]:

mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)
plt.plot(range(10))
Out[5]:
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7354730>]
```

[image]

```
In [6]:

mpl.rcParams.update(inline_rc)
plt.plot(range(10))
Out[6]:
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x75a8e10>]
```

[image]

Basically, `%matplotlib inline` uses its own `rcParams`. You can grab that from the source, but the arguably easier way is probably just save the `rcParams` as `inline_rc` after `%matplotlib inline` cell magic in this example, and reuse that later.

Comment: That gives me the same thing as when I tried matplotlib.rcdefaults(). Does setting the stylesheet change the default parameters?

Comment: Are you using `ipython` `%matplotlib inline`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `ipython %matplotlib inline`

Comment: Actually, I'm using `ipython notebook` with `%matplotlib inline` - in case that makes a difference

Comment: Yep, that makes a lot of difference. `inline` cell magic uses a different `rcParams`

Comment: Getting this:'The examples.directory rcparam was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.0 and will be removed in 3.2. In the future, examples will be found relative to the 'datapath' directory.'

Comment: Strangely enough, figure size still doesn't get reset with this method.

Answer (score 57):

There actually is a `default`. But it's not listed under `plt.style.available`. Simply run :

```
plt.style.use('default')
```

It returns the style to the default Matplotlib settings in, for instance, Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the [answer by CT Zhu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26413529/2707864), the differences between the `inline` and `matplotlib` defaults are (for each item that is different, a list with the to respective values is given):

```
inline_default_rc = dict(mpl.rcParams)
default_rc = dict(mpl.rcParamsDefault)
print( {k:[v,default_rc[k]] for k,v in inline_default_rc.items() if v != default_rc[k]} )

{'figure.dpi': [72.0, 100.0], 'figure.edgecolor': [(1, 1, 1, 0), 'white'], 'figure.facecolor': [(1, 1, 1, 0), 'white'], 'figure.figsize': [[6.0, 4.0], [6.4, 4.8]], 'figure.subplot.bottom': [0.125, 0.11], 'interactive': [True, False]}
```

You can use this to fine tune your plots.