# Importing seaborn in python script messing up plot style

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Attached below are two plots. The only difference in the script that produced them is that the second one had an additional line:

```
import seaborn as sns
```

I am not setting any seaborn style yet. Just importing seaborn is changing plot style though, even in plots not using seaborn. Is there any way I can import seaborn (to be used in other plots), and not have the style changed for plots that do not use it?

Comment: What's the difference?, only the bg?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413185/how-to-recover-matplotlib-defaults-after-setting-stylesheet. Basically, `seaborn` has its own `rcparams` and will override `matplotlib` default.  Manually revert it back to `matplotlib` default after `import seaborn` is required.

Comment: @AlvaroJoao I want the ticks!!!

Comment: http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/installing.html#importing-seaborn

Comment: thanks @mwaskom for an excellent package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this

*`import seaborn.apionly as sns or from seaborn.apionly import lmplot`*

http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/whatsnew.html