# pandas.scatter_matrix function started to draw fuzzy and corrupted plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

Function of pandas.scatter_matrix stopped to work well in Jupyter Notebook.

All the time it drew this plot:

[image]

And now it shows this way:

[image]

And I can't figure out, what affected this.

What can be the reason?

**UPDATE**

Looks like usage of seaborn heatmap in previous cells damages the function.

How to recover from seaborn.heatmap?

**UPDATE 2**

```
matplotlib.style.use('classic')
```

didn't recover completely

[image]

**UPDATE 3**

The following command

```
plt.rcParams.update(plt.rcParamsDefault)
```

also recovers only partially.

Comment: this usually happens after the `import seaborn` command, but `matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')` gives you the same or very similar effect, so try to play with `matplotlib.style.use(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

As stated in [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26413529/5741205):

> `%matplotlib inline` uses its own `rcParams`. You can grab that from the
>   source, but the arguably easier way is probably just save the
>   `rcParams` as `inline_rc` after `%matplotlib inline` cell magic in
>   this example, and reuse that later.

```
saved_plt_params = plt.rcParams  # call it before `import seaborn` !
import seaborn
...
plt.rcParams = saved_plt_params
```

**OLD answer:**

This should "fix" the style:

```
matplotlib.style.use('classic')
```

NOTE: you may want to read about [matplotlib styles](http://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html)

DEMO:

```
In [4]: s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100)).add(.1).cumsum()

In [5]: %matplotlib
Using matplotlib backend: Qt5Agg

In [6]: s.plot()
Out[6]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xbe16d68>
```

[image]

after we executed `import seaborn`:

```
In [7]: import seaborn

In [8]: s.plot()
Out[8]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xf4782e8>
```

[image]

let's "fix" it:

```
In [10]: plt.style.use('classic')

In [11]: s.plot()
Out[11]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xf6e3cc0>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is style? Plot looks not only differently styled, but corrupted: grid lines are fragmentary and not uniform. Anyway, thanks for helping, but the mode didn't recover by your command by 100%

Comment: @Dims, it's hard to see the differences on those plots - what is/are they?

Comment: first one has "wireframe" style, second one ("corrupted") has solid backgrounds and dirty grid lines and third ("partially recovered") has gray margins.

Comment: @Dims, sorry it's beyond my matplotlib knowledge... I've added a "matplotlib" tag to your question - this may attract some matplotlib experts

Comment: @Dims, have you seen a foot note of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26413529/5741205)?